# How to handle type of an iterator?

Tags: for-loop, go, types

I have the following piece of code:

```
func generateBoard() {
    for i := 0; i < 64; i++ {

    }
}

func getRank(i int) uint8 {
    return i / 8
}
```

In the loop I want to call `getRank(i)`. I want `getRank` return `uint8` cause it's the least integer type and I don't need more. The problem is that I can't divide `int` by `uint8`. I don't want to cast `i` to `uint8` cause it might be expensive(possibly even an allocation happens there). Also I don't want to declare `i` as `uint8` before the loop like:

```
var i uint8
for i = 0; i < 64; i++ {
```

Cause I believe that on the low level initializing iterator in the loop is pretty optimized and  declaring an iterator before would be also not the best solution.
What would be the best implementation of this?

Comment: Also: don't you want the loop to go from `0..63` both inclusive? That would require `i < 64` loop condition.

Comment: @icza Yeah, sure. Typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may declare `getRank()` to take a value of type `uint8`, and also you may use a typed constant when declaring the loop variable, so `i` will be of type `uint8`:

```
func generateBoard() {
    for i := uint8(0); i < 64; i++ {
        fmt.Println(getRank(i)) // Valid
    }
}

func getRank(i uint8) uint8 {
    return i / 8
}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/mmaOqf3XLOH).

You could also use the shift operator instead of dividing by 8:

```
func getRank(i uint8) uint8 {
    return i >> 3
}
```

But this is a micro-optimization that is most likely recognized and used by the compiler too. So use whichever is more expressive in your context.